# Prove that $ \int_1^2\frac{dt}{t} < 1$ using right limit of Riemann sum

Tags: calculus, integration

I am currently trying to prove that $L(2) < 1$, where:

$$L(x) = \int_{1}^{x} \frac{1}{t}\text{d}t$$
Given that we do not assume $L = \ln x$.

What I thought of is that you can use the right Riemann sum, as it will always be greater than $L(x)$. If I prove that $R(x)$ (right Riemann sum) is less than $1$, then $L(x)$ will also be less than $1$.

It would of course be simple to just divide $n$ into a given number of rectangles and get an approximate, but I would much rather like to calculate the limit more generally.

$$R(x) = \sum_{i = 1}^{n}f(x_{i-1}^*)\triangle x$$

$$\triangle x = \frac{b-a}{n} = \frac{1}{n}$$
$$x_{i-1}^* = a + \triangle x (i-1) = 1 + \frac{i-1}{n}$$

And I got to
$$R(x) = \sum_{i = 1}^{n}\frac{n}{n+i}\triangle x$$
** Sorry, I was looking at the result of the left Riemann sum here.
The right expression would be (though I'm sure the math would be the same):
$$R(x) = \sum_{i = 1}^{n}\frac{n}{n+i-1}\triangle x$$
but I cannot seem to somehow find the sum (whether by simplying the expression, splitting or w/e). Am I missing something obvious? Help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

You simply can use the *mean value inequality*:

> If $f$ is integrable and $m\le f(x)\le M$ on $[a,b]$, then
>
> $$ m\le\frac1{b-a}\int_a^b f(x) \;\mathrm dx\le M. $$

Comment: Ahh, yes, thank you! I forgot to mention we are not to assume that L(x) = ln(x), so we would have to solve this using the properties of the integral (?)

Comment: @MCrypa ?? This nowhere uses the logarithm. Let me suggest to reread this post more carefully since it is most likely the answer you were asked to reach.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another possibility, without using the tedious right Riemann sums.

[image: Covered by a trapezoid]

$L(2)$ is less than the area of the trapezoid, which is $$\dfrac{\left(1+\dfrac 12\right)\times 1}2=\dfrac 34<1\;.$$

$f\colon x\mapsto\dfrac 1x$ and $g\colon x\mapsto\dfrac{3-x}2$ are both defined and continuous on $[1,2]$ and we have $f(x)<g(x)$ whenever $1<x<2$ while $f(1)=g(1)=1$ and $f(2)=g(2)=\dfrac 12$.

Hence,
$$\int_1^2 f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x<\int_1^2g(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\;.$$

It implies that
$$L(2)=\int_1^2\dfrac{\mathrm{d}x}x<\int_1^2\dfrac{3-x}2\,\mathrm{d}x=\dfrac 34\;.$$

---

Here is the theorem I've just used:

If $f\colon[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ and $g\colon[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ are continuous, $f\leqslant g$ and if there is at least one number $\alpha$ in $[a,b]$ such that $f(\alpha)<g(\alpha)$, then $$\int_a^b f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x<\int_a^b g(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$$

Answer (score 1):

Since $\dfrac{n}{n+i}<1$, we get

$$\sum_{i = 1}^{n}\frac{n}{n+i}\triangle x=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i = 1}^{n}\frac{n}{n+i}<\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i = 1}^{n}1=1$$

Comment: Thank you very much :)) I think I got it

Comment: This notes that some Riemann sums are $<1$, but the integral is a limit of such sums hence it could well be $1$. Where is the proof?